# How to use Using a inline comparator for a deque of Pair<Integer,Integer> in java

Tags: java

```
Deque<Pair<Integer,Integer>> deque = new LinkedList<Pair<Integer,Integer>>(map.size(),(a,b)->(a.getValue()-b.getValue()));
```

This throws an error as - no suitable constructor found for LinkedList(int,(a,b)->(a.[...]ue()))

Comment: LinkedList has no constructor that takes a Comparator. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A LinkedList does no ordering. The elements are simply added and doubly linked. To sort the input You could use the `new LinkedList<Pair<Integer,Integer>>(Collection<Pair<Integer,Integer>> c)` constructor and define the `Comparator` in the choosen `Collection` eg. in `ArrayList` with `void ArrayList.sort(Comparator<? super E> c)`.